# Doctrine 2 : orm:generate-repositories not working

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I recently integrated zend framework with doctrine 2. I have some issues with generating repository classes. I have no problems generating proxies.

The weird part is when I generate-repositories the output says

Repository classes generated to "/library"

But I cant seem to find the files. Inside my Entity class I have:

```
@Entity(repositoryClass="Entity\Repository\UserRepository")
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Why generate Repository classes? I only takes a minute to write them yourself... :s

Comment: yea I guess. Im just going to write them  myself.

Comment: What was the exact command that you used to generate the repositories?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what is the directory structure you use, but according to most of the guides I found online and the way I implemented it, I guess your `Entity` directory is inside somesort of a `MyApp` directory which is inside the `library` directory.

If this is the case indeed, your `@Entity` line should be:

```
@Entity(repositoryClass="MyApp\Entity\Repository\UserRepository")
```

as opposed to what you wrote

```
@Entity(repositoryClass="Entity\Repository\UserRepository")
```

where `MyApp` is your model's root namespace name.

The `@Entity` line you wrote, should have generated the repository files in `library/Entity/Repository`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the doctrine script with the correct path? This is how run it and it created the repos in the correct place

```
php scripts/doctrine.php orm:generate-repositories library/
```

I think you are using `/library` instead of `library/`

just a thought.

PS: I run this in one level above the document root.

Comment: I tried that. But I get an invalidargument, directory does not exist.

Comment: How is your directory structure and where exactly running the script?